# PHP pagerank API not working in sept. 2012

Tags: pagerank

None of the Google Pageranks APIs are working anymore, pagerank -1.
How do I fix it, are there any working pagerank apis?

Answer (score 1):

Please, visit:
http://php-estudios.blogspot.com.ar/2012/08/pagerank-de-google-con-php.html

Simple solution to Google Page Rank 2012.